# Does the Fluidmaster 400A fill valve have a flow restricter?

Tags: toilet

My toilet tank takes 2 min 11 sec to refill. It uses the Fluidmaster 400A. Water pressure is good and we don't have hard water or sediment. Does the 400A have a flow restrictor in the shank?
I would like to speed up the fill time considerably.

Comment: Instructions for the model just above the 400A: https://www.fluidmaster.com/toilet-problems/remove-toilet-fill-valve-flow-regulator/

Comment: Sounds dumb, but I found this issue in my house - make sure the valve is turned all the way on.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's an old question with no accepted answer from a no-longer user.

Comment: Mine takes about this long as well. I just let it be because a couple mins between flushes is sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, older Flushmaster 400’s had a high pressure limiting insert.  White rubber screw shaped plug that greatly limited flow.  About 1 inch long inserted into inlet pipe where it is threaded for attaching to tank.  Mine was installed about 24 years ago, so may not still be available.

Toilet tank filled very slowly, so I got a new valve and discovered the plug when replacing.  Once removed, old valve worked just as good as the new one.

Answer (score 0):

No, no restrictor but there is a screen in the fill tube.  I'll bet it is plugged with debris.  Happy Hunting P.